# Why is the formation of the nitro isomer more favorable under acidic conditions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, isomers

In the reaction between chloropenataamminecobalt and nitrite either the NO2 or the ONO linkage isomer is formed. This preference seems to be mainly due to the pH of the solution with acidic conditions favoring the N-bound nitro over the O-bound nitrito. does anyone know what causes this I'm thinking it has to do with the formation of nitrous acid in the solution.

Comment: Provide some illustration. Difficult to understand what you're taking about.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out for those wondering. Under acidic conditions, the nitrite molecule forms nitrous acid via an oxygen-hydrogen bond. This makes it so the only atom available for bonding is the nitrogen and thus the nitro (N bonded) isomer is favored.

Comment: Do you have any reference to back your answer?